# WordPress file showing error doesn't exist in my WordPress folders

Tags: wordpress

A file directory that doesn't exist is causing a fatal error on my website. The funniest thing is that the folder doesn't exist at all. Below is the error code.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wpcf7_include_module_file() in /usr/www/users/firsttyqsc/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/constant-contact/constant-contact.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /usr/www/users/firsttyqsc/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/load.php(72): include_once() #1 /usr/www/users/firsttyqsc/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/load.php(38): WPCF7::load_module('constant-contac...') #2 /usr/www/users/firsttyqsc/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/load.php(105): WPCF7::load_modules() #3 /usr/www/users/firsttyqsc/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(305): wpcf7() #4 /usr/www/users/firsttyqsc/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #5 /usr/www/users/firsttyqsc/wp-includes/plugin.php(474): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #6 /usr/www/users/firsttyqsc/wp-settings.php(450): do_action('plugins_loaded') #7 /usr/www/users/firsttyqsc/wp-config.php(92): require_once('/usr/www/users/...') #8 /usr/www/users/firsttyqsc/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/usr/www/users/...') #9 /usr/www/users/ in /usr/www/users/firsttyqsc/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/constant-contact/constant-contact.php on line 8

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: which folder is it?

Answer (score 1):

To get your site back up and running, rename the contact-form-7 plugin folder in wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7 to contact-form-7-2 for example... This will deactivate the plugin and hopefully restore your site back for troubleshooting later. This 'fix' is will not allow the plugin work right away. I recommend reinstalling Contact Form 7 again to see if you can recover your templates. If you have the same problem again, delete the second install folder labeled 'contact-form-7' for tidiness. At this point you will need to delete the backup folder from before, reinstall again, and re-setup your templates.

There appears to be an issue with the Contact Contact integration for Contact Form 7.